# Google Geocoding API daily quota issue

Tags: google-maps

using Google Geocoding API in web try to get the address by lat & long that always sending below message even that one is the first request.

> You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account [results] => Array ( ) [status] => OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Comment: What's the request you are sending?

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$long&key=___

Comment: Have you enabled billing on your account with a credit card?

Comment: no, but one week before that one is working fine. I need to enable billing account?

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same issue for the maps API since last week. If you are consuming the API from **Brazil**, **India** or **Canada**, the new princing plan ([Google Annoucement](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use)) is now under effect:

> To use our Maps, Routes, and Places APIs:
>
> - All Google Maps Platform API requests must include an API key; we no longer support keyless access.
> - You must enable billing on each of your projects.

Therefore, make sure you are using API keys on your requests and enabled billings on your projects.

Comment: we're consuming API from UAE.